# Kendowwindow __RequestVerificationToken

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui-mvc, kendo-window

I am opening an kendo window using the below jquery function.

I need to pass `__RequestVerificationToken` to the MVC Controller because I am having `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` Attribute.

However, I am not able to pass it. Can you please suggest how to pass `__RequestVerificationToken` while opening an `kendoWindow`

```
function OpenTest() {           

   var url =      '@Url.ActionWithArea("OpenTest", "Test", GlobalConst.AREA_Test)';

   url += "?test=" +$("#test").val() +
   "&test1=" +$("#test1").val();


windowElement = $('<div id = "abc" />').kendoWindow({
title: 'test',
content: url,
modal: true,
resizable: false,
draggable: false, 
width: 900,
height: 400,
close: function () {              windowElement.destroy(); }).data("kendoWindow").center().open();

  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to think about including this token at a more global scope in your application so you don't have to meddle with it on a per call basis.

There is an example over on the [Kendo UI forums](http://www.telerik.com/forums/anti-forgery-tokens), about halfway down. The data signature of your route should look like:

```
transport: {
    read: {
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: {__RequestVerificationToken: $("input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]").val()
        }
    }
```

Or in your case, something like this -->

```
'@Url.ActionWithArea("OpenTest", "Test", new { __RequestVerificationToken=<value> }),GlobalConst.AREA_Test)';
```